# Is there a way to continue test scenario execution after step failure in a previous scenario?

Tags: cucumberjs, webdriver-io

Whenever there is a step failure while running on a remote server, I would like to capture the failed step and then continue running the remaining scenarios. The captured step would then be included in a file for reporting purposes. Is this a possibility? All replies I've seen elsewhere just say you should fix the test before moving on. I agree, but I only want the tests to stop when running locally, not remotely.

`➜  customer git:(pat104) ✗ cucumber.js -f progress                                                                                                    (pat104⚡)
...F-----Failed scenario: View and select first contact from contact history
...F-Failed scenario: View and select a contact from multiple contacts in history
..................................................F---Failed scenario: Navigating to profile with url and enrollmentId
...................................................F-Failed scenario: Successful MDN Search with 1 result returned. Tech Selects and continues
.............FFailed scenario: Successful MDN with multiple results`

Comment: Can you add the command you are using to run the test && the output you are getting?  What are you using for reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, one of the step-definitions was using .waitForExist incorrectly. The test was written:

```
this.browser
        .waitForExist('#someElement', 1000, callback)
```

Callback isn't a parameter for .waitForExist, rewrote to:

```
.waitForExist('#someElement',1000).then(function (exists) {
            assert.equal(exists, true, callback);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior, isn't it?  Example command

```
cucumber.js -f json > cucumberOutput.json
```

Comment: No, if I run the tests with `cucumber-js -f progress`  the step still breaks the test and doesn't continue.

Comment: This is key as test should always continue to run.

Comment: I now have a test that fails, which stops cucumber execution, and no json is produced at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, that you need to manage in your test itself using `callback.fail(e)` like below. You can use library like [grunt-cucumberjs](https://github.com/mavdi/grunt-cucumberjs) to add these errors to nice HTML reports.

```
this.Then(/^the save to wallet button reflects the offer is saved$/, function (callback) {
        merchantPage(this.nemo).doStuff().then(function () {
            callback();
        }, function (e) {
            callback.fail(e); //add this to report
        });
});
```

Or you could use [Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#hooks) and check whether a scenario is failed and report (take screenshot or add logging etc.)

```
 this.After(function (scenario, callback) {
        var driver = this.nemo.driver;
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
            driver.takeScreenshot().then(function (buffer) {
                scenario.attach(new Buffer(buffer, 'base64').toString('binary'), 'image/png');
            });
        }
        driver.quit().then(function () {
                callback();
       });
 });
```

Comment: After adding this to the test, it still skips the remaining scenarios in the feature after a step failure. Also, having to add this to every test seems pretty messy.

Comment: [one of] the issues is that her tests are stopping even though there is no .quit() in the .After() hook.  Have you seen this when there are exceptions? I think I have.